# Would stainless steel or titanium punched tape be feasible for data achiving?

Tags: materials

I was thinking of ways to archive simple data for a long, long, long time. So I thought of punched tape with data stored as 7 bit ASCII. Just go with me on this :-) Something like:-

[image: tape]

The above is actually aluminized Mylar, but looks like what I'm asking about. For example, my PGP secret key is approx 7000 characters long. I would need $\approx$18m of tape for a standard 'paper' tape dot pitch of 0.1". Which I'd hope to store rolled up in a can.

Can this be achieved with stainless or titanium?

Comment: Why not chisel it into a piece of rock? less delicate machinery needed to retrieve it.

Comment: Titanium , it would be much more expensive.

Comment: @SolarMike Would it fit through a tape reader?

Comment: Would you class a tape reader as "delicate"?

Comment: IMO, dot pitch of 0.1" is excessive. 0.031" would be plenty.

Comment: @DKNguyen I only used that pitch as it's the original pitch in paper tape.

Comment: What makes you think the tape puncher can punch metal?

Comment: @EricS Do you think that a 100kW laser can't?

Comment: No where in you question do you say you are using a 100kW laser. Some paper tape punches are actually mechanical punches. 100kW seems to be overkill for paper or mylar.

Comment: @EricS But what about titanium ribbon?

Comment: This looks like it takes up more space than printed text.

Comment: Other things to consider for long term storage is oxidation of the metal tape & whether the tape should be stored in a sealed container in either a vacuum or inert gas. Storage in the dark would also be advisable, as would keeping it dry. Some metals, such as tin, can develop [whiskers](https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/inspection-technical-guides/tin-wiskers-problems-causes-and-solutions) or other blemishes, which would be problematic. Such whiskers could grow over holes.

Comment: Using punched tape would be better than punched cards as card, made of the same material, as cards could be placed out of sequence, back to front, upside down or even lost. I also question why you would want to use a 7 bit system from the 1960s & 1970s. A new system could be developed on a metal tape medium that had more holes of a smaller size. It might even be possible to have dimples instead of holes, something like inverse "Braille". This would allow more data to be stored on given length of tape.

Comment: @Fred 7 bit ASCII is human readable, and a hand pulled optical reader can be built with Lego or wood (do a search for all the DIY projects). Consider that Hieroglyphs can be read from millions of years ago whilst I can't read my floppies. It just works.

Comment: @Fred, why inverse Braille? Stay the course and dimple the tape in true Braille.

Comment: @fred_dot_u: dimples being read by a laser, a bit like pits on CDs.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is specifically to determine if this can be achieved with stainless (steel) or titanium, the answer would be that it is not advised. Stainless steel is available in various alloys and is not listed in the [ductility charts](https://www.failurecriteria.com/physicalductilit.html) I've found. Titanium is listed and is less ductile than many other common metals. Chart below from linked page.

[image: ductility chart]

Copper, tin, and aluminum are likely to be much less expensive than titanium. Stainless steel is "typically" less flexible than other alloys of iron, but may be durable if the archived tape is not manipulated frequently.

My research shows that archival grade paper tape can survive decades of storage. The mylar tape in your image also qualifies in that respect. Mylar tape is common, durable, inexpensive and can be considered metal, as it is a metal film on a polyester substrate.

Comment: Titanium also has a no fatigue limit.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't just the longevity of the media, but also the ability to read the media. There are people who have backed up on floppies, Zip disks and other formats that have no ability to read the media on modern computers. The odds that your tape reader will be connectable to a computer in the future is pretty low. Also, there is the question of how long you really need the archive to last. Archival paper can last hundreds of years if pigmented ink is used and it is stored appropriately (dry and in the dark).

I would suggest considering just printing your data on archival bond paper using a common 2D barcode format. Most ink jet printers use pigmented inks for black so that should be stable for many, many decades. You can use any available digital camera to read the barcode so that part of the process should be future proof. If you are worried about using a barcode, you could print to text and use OCR to read but this is less accurate than a barcode.

Comment: I would argue that you could use a digital camera to read punch paper too. And in a pinch, you could read a punch card by eye whereas it would be a lot more difficult with a barcode. Making devices to read punch cards is also easier if this is supposed to be civilziation surviving.

Comment: @DKNguyen reading barcodes or text is already solved. The software is and will be available. Plain text printing will be easier to read manually too. Also it doesn’t seem likely that a punch device designed for paper is necessarily going to punch metal.

Comment: Plain text printing would be more easily read by a human but not as easily read by "simple" technology which the OP seems to want by mention of a PGP key. I am not sure of the OP's context but I am approaching this from a doomsday time capsule perspective.

Comment: @DKNguyen I understand where you’re coming from. That said, if there is no technology available to read the PGP key, then a PGP key is probably of little value.

Comment: Heh yeah........

Comment: As a "youngster" in high school, many years ago (last century), I amused myself by using the computer terminal connected to the University many miles away by dial-up and converting my homework Basic programs to paper tape. It was fun until authorities decided to remove that resource. Additional amusement was reading the dots/holes on the paper and matching them to my entered code. As @DKNguyen suggests, the MK 1 eyeball is capable.

Comment: Simple formats come with *significantly* higher odds that someone can make a new reader able to be connected to future computers. That is why you would use punched tape rather than say M-Disc CDs.